# Determining sample size of a set of boolean data where the probability is not 50%

Tags: probability

I'll lay out the problem as a simplified puzzle of what I am attempting to calculate. I imagine some of this may seem fairly straightforward to many but I'm starting to get a bit lost in my head while trying to think through the problem.

Let's say I roll a 1000-sided die until it lands on the number 1. Let's say it took me 700 rolls to get there. I want to prove that the first 699 rolls were not number 1 and obviously the only way to deterministically do this is to include the first 699 failures as part of the result to show they were in fact "not 1".

However, that's a lot of data I would need to prove this. I would have to include all 700 rolls, which is a lot. Therefore, I want to probabilistically demonstrate the fact that I rolled 699 "not 1s" prior to rolling a 1. To do this, I decide I will randomly sample my "not 1" rolls to reduce the set to a statistically significant, yet more wieldy number. It will be good enough to demonstrate that I very probably did not roll a 1 prior to roll 700.

Here are my current assumptions about the state of this problem:

- My initial experiment of rolling until success is one of geometric distribution.
- However my goal for this problem is to demonstrate to a third party that I am not lying, therefore the skeptical third party is not concerned with geometric distribution but would view this simply as a binomial distribution problem.

A lot of sample size calculators exist on the web. They are all based around binomial distribution from what I can tell. So here's the formula I am considering:

$$
n = \frac{N \times X}{X + N – 1}
$$

$$
X = \frac{{Z_{\alpha/2}}^2 ­\times p \times (1-p)}{\mathsf{MOE}^2}
$$

- $n$ is sample size
- $N$ is population size
- $Z$ is critical value ($\alpha$ is $1-\mathsf{confidence\space level\space as\space probability}$)
- $p$ is sample proportion
- $\mathsf{MOE}$ is margin of error

As an aside, the website where I got this formula says it implements "finite population correction", is this desirable for my requirements?

Here is the math executed on my above numbers. I will use $Z_{a/2}=2.58$ for $\alpha=0.01$, $p=0.001$ and $\mathsf{MOE}=0.005$. As stated above, $N=699$ on account of there being 699 failure cases that I would like to sample with a certain level of confidence.

Based on my understanding, what this math will do is recommend a sample size that will show, with 99% confidence, that the sample result is within 0.5 percentage points of reality.

Doing the math, $X=265.989744$ and $n=192.8722086653\approx193$, implying that I can have a sample size of 193 to fulfill this confidence level and interval.

My main question is whether my assumption about $p=\frac{1}{1000}$ is valid. If it's not, and I use the conservative $p=0.5$, then my sample size shoots up to $\approx692$. So I would like to know if my assumptions about what sample proportion actually is are correct.

More broadly, am I on the right track at all with this? From my attempt at demonstrating this probabilistically to my current thought process, is any of this accurate at all? Thank you.

Comment: I don’t understand what your question is. Are you asking how large of a sample size one needs to be sure of a biased proportion estimate to be within a confidence interval? The fact that $p \neq 1/2$ seems irrelevant to me.

Comment: I guess what I’m asking is how can I get a sample size such that I can demonstrate that the trials I personally know all failed actually did all fail (probabilistically speaking). Deterministically, I could give a skeptic verifier 699 failed dice rolls. Probabilistically, I could give them a random sample of n failed dice rolls. How can I find n? Or, and I’m open to this as well, am I completely off base with regards to this being a valid solution to proving my dice rolls?

Comment: I still do not follow, sorry. If I wanted to convince a skeptic about the failure rate of a *random* experiment I am just going to measure the proportion of successes, $\hat{p}$ and find how many trials, $N$, I need to perform so that my confidence interval is sufficiently small and then translate this into a CI for the failure percentage, $\hat{q}=1-\hat{p}$. I still fail to see how this doesn't even marginally satisfy your aim.

Comment: Let me be a bit less abstract about the problem, I attempted to write it out in a more isolated way, but the actual problem I am attempting to solve requires the experiment as it is run to be the canonical result. Imagine a POW scheme where a nonce incrementing by 1 from 0 is used to find a hash that has a specific trailing number of 0 bits. Once a nonce is reached that satisfies this, that POW is valid. Unlike most POWs, I want there to be only 1 valid answer (the first success). Is it possible to sample my failures in a way that probabilistically shows I didn't illicitly skip a success?

Comment: Now you've really lost me. This is a math forum, remember, not every one here is going to know to what a POW scheme refers... Anyway, if I run an experiment $N$ times with the only and first success on trial $n=N$, and you want to validate this, then yes the easiest way to is to show you the first recorded $N-1$ outcomes of failure. If the outcomes are recorded in some data structure/spreadsheet, one can easily count them with a simple function. No probabilistic method is required because there is no longer any source of uncertainty after the experiment is done.

Comment: Yeah that's why I wanted to reduce it to a math problem. Anyway that's true about storing the result set but the problem there is that for the scales of numbers I'm actually working with, that result will be way too large. While the skeptic could re-run the experiment themselves (easier than storing all of the results), I was hoping for a shortcut that would give the skeptic a smaller set of data that could be verified. Imagine for example 1/(2^20) probability with 100s of thousands of failure cases where "rolling the dice" is purposefully intensive to do.

Comment: Maybe you should consider adding a false-negative distribution to the actual measurement process in addition to the success-failure distribution of the outcomes themselves. That way you can at least assign a probability to the event "an outcome from the experiment being recorded as a failure while truly being a success". Otherwise, it seems moot to me to even use a probabilistic method (the measurements are always accurate)—just show them the entire sample set, or as large as effectively possible to convince them. Anyway, sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 1):

If the method you have chosen to analyze your problem of rolling a die is selecting a sample from a population which involves taking into account a finite population (correction factor), which means "without replacement" and hence there can be a difference of $p = .001$ for all rolls versus an increase in $p$ as your sample size increases which is "not desirable for your requirements".

However, analyzing it as a one proportion $Z$ test, with $n = 699$, $x = 0$, and $p_0 = .001$, the $p$ value is $.4029$ versus $.4969$ by Daniel Mathias's method for a die roll. In both cases such a high $p$ value indicates that getting $699$ failures is not statistically significant for either a proportion or a probability of $.001$.

Answer (score 0):

If the probability of success is $S=0.001$ then the probability of failure is $F=0.999$ and the probability of 699 failures without success is $F^{699}\approx0.4969$

Comment: When I read about sample proportions online, they always use examples like 60% of college students are women therefore the sample proportion would lean towards 0.6, which seems like it maps to my problem using 0.001 or 0.999 (both have same result) rather than using the failure^number of times for sample proportion. Am I misunderstanding?